# Custom Css for the angular-6-datatable

Tags: css, angular, datatable

I am using the [Angular-6-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable). i want to apply some custom CSS for the table header and the paginator icons. how can we override the current CSS with the custom CSS [image: angular-6-datatable screenshot] i have a global css file where i am adding the  color for the "a" tag. in the package they are using 
`@Input("by") sortBy: string;`

and  appending it with the template

`<a style="cursor: pointer;color: #ffffff;" (click)="sort()" class="text-nowrap">
            <ng-content></ng-content>
            <span *ngIf="isSortedByMeAsc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span *ngIf="isSortedByMeDesc" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>`

i tried giving the color in the template there at the run time when i inspect the element i see no color property.

here is the stackblitz link : [stackblitz Application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdx6pc)

Comment: It's just a Bootstrap styled table. In app.component.html, simply style the table as you want with CSS in the normal way: `<table class="table table-striped"` and use your own classes instead of bootstrap ones.

Comment: You are required to a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and NEVER any third party site!

Comment: i have my own css file where i am overriding the "a" tag with some color, if you c the thead part <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Age</mfDefaultSorter> . they are using the @Input("by") sortBy: string; and appending the <a> with the template. i want to change the color of that <a> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding the following code in style.css we can override the property

`table > thead >  tr> th > mfdefaultsorter > a {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-weight: bold;
  }`

Answer (score -2):

You can just select a different css file in your app component.
For instance:

```
  @Component({
  selector: 'your-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
  })
```

You can just make a new CSS file and edit the styleUrl line.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I'm pretty new on Stack and i received a lot of help from you guys whilst preparing for my OCA. I thought i'd start to return the favour. I added a piece of code to clarify. Is this up to standard?

Comment: This is far better. Always explain your code which is a constant problem on SO nowadays as people just blurt code out with no explanation.